# Simulate different domains on the same machine

Tags: domain, domain-name-system

I'm going to have 2 servers (SSO and application server) running on the same machine but listening on different ports. Is it possible to assign them following addresses: *example.com* and *app.example.com* so that the second would be a subdomain of the first?

How would I achieve this? would I use a `hosts` file or `Active Directory`?

**Edit**:
I'm not going to use IIS. I want to test [OpenAM](http://openam.forgerock.org/) product which will be deployed as **Tomcat** application (most likely listening on 8080 port), and I want to install OpenAM policy agent on **Glassfish** application server which will host some web application probably listening on 9090 port.
Now what I want to achieve is to redirect all **example.com** requests to 10.11.11.22:8080 and **app.example.com** to 10.11.11.22:9090.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have more than one website running on the same web server, using host headers / [virtual hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting). This is a mechanism where the web server looks at the hostname the browser supplied (used to reach the web server) and serves content from the appropriate website.

You don't even need to define different ports for http websites if you define them each with unique host headers. If you'd rather have different ports then this is also pretty easy in most web servers (you don't say what web server you're using).

As for how to set up the names of the sites, this is also fairly easy, though its not really anything to do with active directory, and I wouldn't *personally* use hosts files for anything other than dev testing on a local webserver. You would simply create entries in DNS for the two website addresses, pointing to the web server.

So you'd create an "A" record for the hostname & IP address of the web server itself (e.g. *mywebserver.example.com*) and then use two "CNAME" records (aliases) that point *example.com* and *app.example.com* at that A record. This tells any client that looks up either of those two website addresses in DNS to use the IP address defined for the webserver itself.

**update to address edit**

There's no way to have port number included in in a host name or IP address. Your users will have to type in example.com:8080 and app.example.com:9090. What you're asking for is outside the scope of what can be done in DNS or hosts files because its not related to *name* resolution.

The two ways to get around that that I can think of would be

1. To create two seperate virtual servers, each with the application installed on a webserver listening on port 80.
2. Install IIS (or whatever) on port 80 and have a site for each host header there, as I describe above. Then use redirection from each site to the "correct" one listening at whatever port.

Comment: The problem is that, there will be 2 different servers running on the same machine, but listening on different ports. So I think it's not enough to just create 2 aliases which would redirect to the same server. What I want to achieve is to point *example.com* to 10.11.11.22:8080 and *app.example.com* to 10.11.11.22:9090.

Comment: @jfrentic - updated answer to address your edit and comment to me. Your edit changes the scope of the question quite a bit!

Answer (score 3):

You can either use your `hosts` file or your dns server, whichever is easiest, usually `hosts` unless you need to have the servers available from outside your machine.

As you mention Active Directory I'm going to assume you're using Window/IIS in which case the actions you'll need to take are:

1. Populate your hosts file / DNS server with example.com and app.example.com pointing to the appropriate IP address (*Note: You can assign different IP addresses to each domain name and have your machine have multiple IP addresses, should you wish*)
2. Configure multiple websites in IIS Manager and apply a host-header binding to each of them.

If it is indeed the case that you're hosting these within IIS, you can have them both listening on port 80, should you choose as IIS will direct the traffic to the appropriate site depending on what host-header iot comes in on, i.e. example.com or app.example.com